# If logged-in user's username is in a list, do this, else do that

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display some content only for the following usernames: Admin, Jake, Shadow, Kid.

My current code is something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script' );
function load_script(){
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    // Display content only for the following usernames: Admin, Jake, Shadow, Kid.
} else { 
    // User is not logged in or is logged in but not in the list.
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use following code

```
function load_script(){
  if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    // Display content only for the following usernames: Admin, Jake, Shadow, Kid.
    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // to get currently logged in user

    if($user && isset($user->user_login) && in_array($user->user_login, array('Admin', 'Jake', 'Shadow', 'Kid') ) ) { // check if logged in user is in list
        // do stuff
    } else { 
        // User is logged in but not in the list.
    }

  } else { 
    // User is not logged in.
  }
}
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: i was sure about code but i used words you could try to give respect to questioner

Comment: What do you mean "give respect to the questioner"? It is respectful to provide an explanation.